# Store a symmetric key in Java Keystore

Tags: encryption, java, asymmetric, secure-coding, spring-framework

It is common to use store key pairs in Keystores. I need to store a symmetric key and distribute it in different servers (which are running set of Spring Micro services)

How exactly can I do that and store a symmetric key in a Java Keystore?

Comment: You don't.  Java's keystore is a storage for certificates that may work as a CA.  A certificate with a symmetric key does not makes sense, that key must be secret to have any meaningful use.

Comment: The outgoing default keystore type JKS and main alternate PKCS12 do not support symmetric keys, but JCEKS does, since 1.4 IIRC. Use JCEKS and see [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html). @grochmal 'normal' KeyStores support both `TrustedCertificate` used (alone) as a CA trust anchor and `PrivateKey` which _includes_ matching certificate chain used for an SSL/TLS server (including HTTPS) or client or message signer or decrypter among other things, although some people prefer not to combine these in the same file.